# Using SMXMY2() by referencing named ranges

Tags: excel

I would like to use SUMXMY2() by only using named ranges, but have been running into problems.
Basically I am trying to sum the square of the differences of each value of a subset from a single value

I first started with basic data to understand the formula and make sure it was doing what I wanted, that went fine. I then moved to try to include only named ranges. The first challenge was to create an array out of a single value which was done by using the INDEX() technique: INDEX((5*ROW(1:8))/ROW(1:8),) but that already breaks down when used with named ranges.

Here is the mess:

```
SUMXMY2(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)),  
index((AVERAGE(INDEX(NamedRange,  
MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))*  
row(1:count(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))))/  
row(1:count(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))),))
```

As said earlier, I am trying to sum the square of the differences of each value of a subset from a single value. This just gives me NA. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without out the formula, but am completely stuck

Comment: `row($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,count(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))))`

Comment: That works great to create the first array thanks! I'm trying to get it to work with the SUMXMY2 now
Edit: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for those interested

```
=SUMXMY2(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)),INDEX((AVERAGE(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$6,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))*ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0))))))/ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0))))),))+
SUMXMY2(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$6,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0)),INDEX((AVERAGE(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$6,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$5,COB_Date,0)))*ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$6,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0))))))/ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$6,COB_Date,0)):INDEX(NamedRange,MATCH($C$4,COB_Date,0))))),))
```